# Como suavizar a transição entre as páginas no windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, xaml

Como melhoro a transição *page from page* no Windows Phone?

Porque sempre quando troco de página, ela muda como se fosse "do nada", não aparece suave, como uma transição normal.

Tem *efeitos* específicos pra isso? É necessário algum *framework*? Se sim, qual? E como implementar?

Como eu chamo outras páginas:

`C#`

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pais.xaml?lg=" + lg, UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Você pode dar um exemplo de como implementa atualmente? Com isso as respostas podem ser mais adequadas para a sua solução ;)

Comment: Atualmente não tem nada implementado, não tem nenhum efeito de transição. Queria saber como faço pra colocar esse efeito..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solução:

Instale pelo `Package Manager Console` esse pacote `pm> Install-Package WPToolkit`. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após a instalação você vai seguir os seguintes passos

1) Vai no `App.xaml.cs` em `InitializePhoneApplication` e altere `RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();` para `RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();`, ficando assim:

```
private void InitializePhoneApplication()
{
            if (phoneApplicationInitialized)
                return;

            RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();
            RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;
            RootFrame.NavigationFailed += RootFrame_NavigationFailed;
            RootFrame.Navigated += CheckForResetNavigation;
            phoneApplicationInitialized = true;
}
```

2) Adicione em todas páginas as seguintes tags

Dentro de **`<phone:PhoneApplicationPage`** adicione essa linha:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
     xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

e fora dela essas tags

```
      <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

ficando a primeira parte de todas as paginas assim:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"    
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid ....
```

A partir de todos esses ajustes só criar as páginas e fazer o comando padrão de navegação
`NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(...`

***Referência:***

- [The Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/)
- [August 2013 - Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/releases/view/107923)
- [Windows Phone 7 Navigation Transitions Step By Step guide](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-7-navigation-transitions-step-by-step-guide)